# Unable to install angularfire2 on Ionic 2@RC1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm working on integration of Ionic 2 app with firebase.While trying to install angularfire2 on Ionic 2 RC1 release. I get this error. How can I fix this dependency issue?

```
 $ npm install angularfire2 --save
    ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @types/request@0.0.30
    └── angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.5 

$ ionic info
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.9 
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issues by installing the dependencies

```
npm install @types/request@0.0.30 --save

npm install @types/jasmine@^2.5.36 --save

npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
```

Got some warnings, but the packages got installed

```
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.1.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
```